# Why does this wxPython GUI freeze when self.Destroy() is used instead of self.Close()? (example attached)

Tags: python, wxpython, freeze

`LoginDialog` is opened with `self.loginButton`, and upon closing it, the GUI freezes; the login button remains pressed, and there are only alert sounds when attempting to click on anything.

`LoginDialog()` was from this [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/07/11/wxpython-how-to-create-a-login-dialog/), just augmented with the file-write line in `onLogin` (which isn't the problem source). All appears to work when switching from self.Destroy() to self.Close().

wxPython version is 3.0, Python 2.7.10

The following code is a working example of the issue:

```
import wx

# wxGlade dependency
import gettext

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.updateLoginButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("Store/Update Login"))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.updateLogin, self.updateLoginButton)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle(_("Dialog Test"))

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 1, 1, 0)

        exportButtons_sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 1, 1, 10)
        exportButtons_sizer.Add(self.updateLoginButton, 0, wx.TOP | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 15)

        grid_sizer_1.Add(exportButtons_sizer, 0, wx.TOP | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 20)

        sizer_1.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15)

        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

    def updateLogin(self, event):
        dlg = LoginDialog(self, -1)
        dlg.ShowModal()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
        frame_1.Show()
        return True

class LoginDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """
    Class to define login dialog
    """

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title="Update Login Info"):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        # user info
        user_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        user_lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Username:")
        user_sizer.Add(user_lbl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.user = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        user_sizer.Add(self.user, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        # pass info
        p_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        p_lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Password:")
        p_sizer.Add(p_lbl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.password = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PASSWORD | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        p_sizer.Add(self.password, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(user_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        main_sizer.Add(p_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="OK")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onLogin)
        main_sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

        self.__set_properties()

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onLogin(self, event):
        """
        Check credentials and login
        """
        password = self.password.GetValue()
        email = self.user.GetValue()

        with open('login.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(email + ', ' + password)

        self.Destroy()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.user.SetMinSize((220, 20))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gettext.install("app")

    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Honestly your codes run all right on my side, `python 2.7.3` and `wxpython 3.0.2` on windows 7 64bit

Comment: Freezing of gui's is down to long running code blocking the gui's mainloop. Writing to file must be blocking.

Comment: add some print statements to see where your code freezes

Comment: I discovered that it doesn't freeze when `self.Close()` is used instead of `self.Destroy`. I'm not sure why.

Comment: if you call close() and then destroy will it freeze? Or try calling EndModal

Answer (score 1):

If a dialog is intended to be used with `ShowModal` dialog then the dialog should call `EndModal` when it is done, and the caller should be the one who calls `Destroy` after it has fetched values from the dialog if needed.